# Excluding few options in HelpFormatter.printHelp() using apache-commons-cli

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I am working with apache-commons-cli for parsing command line arguments in my java program.

Now, I am trying to find a way to exclude displaying some *sensitive* or *debug* options from the **usage help**. I am using `HelpFormatter` for the help by the way.

```
Option first = Option.builder("f").hasArg().desc("First argument").build();
Option second = Option.builder("s").hasArg().desc("Second argument").build();
Option debug = Option.builder("d").hasArg().desc("Debug argument. Shouldn't be displayed in help").build();

commandOptions.addOption(first).addOption(second).addOption(debug);

HelpFormatter help = new HelpFormatter();
help.printHelp("Test App", commandOptions);
```

This is printing all the options. But I don't want the third option to be printed.

**Actual Output:**

```
usage: Test App
 -d <arg>   Debug argument. Shouldn't be displayed in help // This shouldn't be displayed.
 -f <arg>   First argument
 -s <arg>   Second argument
```

**Expected Output:**

```
usage: Test App
 -f <arg>   First argument
 -s <arg>   Second argument
```

This way, the debug arguments will be known only to the people who actual need to know about it for debugging.

Is there a way to disable a specific option from the **help output alone**. But still parse it just like any other option?

I am using [`commons-cli-1.3.1.jar`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/download_cli.cgi) by the way.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I see `HelpFormatter` is not intended to be subclassed for something like this, especially `appendOption()` is private and thus does not allow to filter out options.

Therefore I would simply build two `Options` objects, one for actual parsing of the commandline options and one for printing the help, i.e.

```
Option first = Option.builder("f").hasArg().desc("First argument").build();
Option second = Option.builder("s").hasArg().desc("Second argument").build();
Option debug = Option.builder("d").hasArg().desc("Debug argument. Shouldn't be displayed in help").build();

commandOptions.addOption(first).addOption(second).addOption(debug);

helpOptions.addOption(first).addOption(second);
HelpFormatter help = new HelpFormatter();
help.printHelp("Test App", helpOptions);
```